# how do i parse adobe xml swidtag using bash and xmllint

Tags: macos, bash, unix, namespaces, xmllint

Below I have an example of an Adobe XML swidtag used to track inventory. I need to parse out relevant information using bash and output that to a new text file. FYI I'm using terminal on a mac.

For example I would like to parse the following

```
swid:entitlement_required_indicator
swid:product_title
swid:product_version
swid:name
swid:numeric
swid:major
swid:minor
swid:build
swid:review
```

I have tried using

```
xmllint --xpath '//swid:product_version/swid:name/text()' nameoffile.xml
```

Sample tag file for Creative Suite 5
The following sample is for Adobe Photoshop CS5 serialized as Creative Suite 5 Master Collection (Suite)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<swid:software_identification_tag xsi:schemaLocation="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19770/-2/2008/schema.xsd software_identification_tag.xsd" 
     xmlns:swid="http://standards.iso.org/iso/19770/-2/2008/schema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<!--Mandatory Identity elements -->
<swid:entitlement_required_indicator>true</swid:entitlement_required_indicator>
<swid:product_title>Acrobat XI Pro</swid:product_title>
<swid:product_version>
    <swid:name>1.0</swid:name>
    <swid:numeric>
        <swid:major>1</swid:major>
        <swid:minor>0</swid:minor>
        <swid:build>0</swid:build>
        <swid:review>0</swid:review>
    </swid:numeric>
</swid:product_version>
<swid:software_creator>
    <swid:name>Adobe Systems Incorporated</swid:name>
    <swid:regid>regid.1986-12.com.adobe</swid:regid>
</swid:software_creator>
<swid:software_licensor>
    <swid:name>Adobe Systems Incorporated</swid:name>
    <swid:regid>regid.1986-12.com.adobe</swid:regid>
</swid:software_licensor>
<swid:software_id>
    <swid:unique_id>CreativeCloud-CS6-Mac-GM-MUL</swid:unique_id>
    <swid:tag_creator_regid>regid.1986-12.com.adobe</swid:tag_creator_regid>
</swid:software_id>

<swid:tag_creator>
    <swid:name>Adobe Systems Incorporated</swid:name>
    <swid:regid>regid.1986-12.com.adobe</swid:regid>
</swid:tag_creator>
<!--Optional Identity elements -->
<swid:license_linkage>
    <swid:activation_status>activated</swid:activation_status>
    <swid:channel_type>SUBSCRIPTION</swid:channel_type>
    <swid:customer_type>RETAIL</swid:customer_type>
</swid:license_linkage>
<swid:serial_number>909702426602037824854600</swid:serial_number>
</swid:software_identification_tag>
```

Comment: `bash` is probably not the right tool to parse html or xml. Use specialized library in other languages (e.g., perl or python) instead.

Comment: or install `xmlstartlet`. Numerous posts here on S.O. will show you how to use it. ELSE post what you have tried with xmllint and why it is failing. Complete text of error messages are helpful too (if you get any). Good luck.

Comment: Please post the error message/output you are getting? I have used `xmllint` and it had worked like a charm...

Comment: [How do I parse namespaces from an XML file using XMLLINT and BASH][1]

  [1]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56826/43764

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstand your question.  Why doesn't

`grep '<swid:' inputfile | sed 's/<\/.*//'`

or something very close to it (eg proper escaping) work?